# checkbox data submit using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the value of the checkbox as 1 or 0 according to selection. If it is checked then 1 is sent to a PHP file else 0 is sent. The value is sent using a onClick event in the html, using AJAX I want to send the value.

I'm new to AJAX so unable to figure out a way to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: No i was asking you want the solution in jquery ?

Comment: It might be easier to change this on the PHP side (if at all possible)...

Comment: @ubercooluk Ya, that is ok, all I want to do is to pass the value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jquery page for .get gives you examples of how to do this.

Comment: I disagree the question is trival and answer is easily searched for.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').delegate('#Yourbuttonid','click',function(){
        var chkval = 0
          if($('#yourcheckboxid').is(':checked')){
            chkval  = 1;
          }
   $.ajax({
       url: "Your_url",
       type: "POST",
       data:{'checkboxvalue':chkval},

       success:function(returndata){


       },error:function(errordata){


       }
     });

   });  

});
```

and in your Php file

You can get the checkbbox value as `echo $_POST['checkboxvalue'];`

Comment: This script is not working. When i check the checkbox, no data get sent.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('element').on('click', function(){
$checkbox = $(':checkbox').prop('checked');
​$.post({ 
          url :'PageWhereYouWanToSend.php'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​,
          data : {​ 'checked' : $checkbox },
          success : function (resp){
                     alert(resp);
                   }
      });
​});​
```

#### References:

[`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[`.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

[`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You used `on` here and the depreciated `live` in my Edit O_o ? :)

Comment: ` data : {​ checked : $checkbox },` in here i think `checked` needs to be in quotes

Comment: because were are using `.click`, so i changed to `.live` , it is better than that. If i changes to `.on` then you may disagree. thats why :)

Comment: Anyway `live is way too depreciated i welcome `delegate` :) :) anyway thanks man !

Answer (score 1):

```
var subcheck = 0;
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      subcheck = 1;
   } else {
      subcheck = 0;
   }


   $.post("your.php", { checkdata: subcheck},
   function(data) {
      //your code here
   });
});
```

Comment: You left .post outside of the .change function so the change would never be posted.